# Extracting details from a database timestamp

Tags: php, mysql

I'm learning about timestamps. I can find lots of infomation about extracting data from current timestamps but little about querying a database timestamp. For example, I'd like to perform the following (the syntax is not correct, but should hopefully illustrate my question)

```
SELECT * FROM database where timestamp DAY('12') AND MONTH('01')
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM database where timestamp MONTH('01') AND YEAR('2009')
```

can you point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 3):

**You can use the MySQL function [`FROM_UNIXTIME()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime).**

```
SELECT * FROM database WHERE DAY(FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp)) = 12 
    AND MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp)) = 1

SELECT * FROM database WHERE MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp)) = 1
    AND YEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp)) = 2009
```

Answer (score 1):

For the second one, a more efficient way would be like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM database
WHERE timestamp BETWEEN
    UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2009-01-01 00:00:00')
    AND
    UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2009-01-31 23:59:59')
```